# Using a shared mail box when connecting to internal company SMTP server through python

Tags: python, email, smtp, shared

I have been granted access by IT to send emails via a shared mail box on an internal smtp server and I can do so though the outlook app and through the win32com libary using outlook. However this program will run on a windows machine without outlook desktop app installed so I need to send this email using the smtplib. I have tried connecting using my personal email and password and then setting the from address to the shared email and it says I don't have permission to send from this address which I do. I have also tried using "SendAs" and "SentOnBehalfOfName" (Commented out below) with the from address as my personal mail and this email is just received as though I sent it from my personal. Any guidance, improvements to the code or solutions to try would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import smtplib 
from email.message import EmailMessage

port = 587

smtp_server = "internal_smtp_host"
sender_email = "personal_company_address"  
receiver_email = "" 
shared_mail = "shared_company_mailbox"
password = "personal_password"

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
msg['From'] = shared_mail
msg['To'] = receiver_email

#Try to log in to server and send email

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    server.connect(smtp_server, port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    #server.SendAs = shared_mail 
    #server.SentOnBehalfOfName = shared_mail 
    server.set_debuglevel(True)
    server.send_message(msg)
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed') 
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have permissions to send emails in behalf of the shared mailbox

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase


def send_email(user,password,SEND_FROM,SEND_TO,SUBJECT,MAIL_BODY):
    multipart = MIMEMultipart()
    multipart['From'] = SEND_FROM
    multipart['To'] = SEND_TO
    multipart['Subject'] = SUBJECT


    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.office365.com', port=587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login(user, password)

    mailserver.sendmail(SEND_FROM, SEND_TO, multipart.as_string())
    mailserver.quit()

user        = '<Your email account>'
password    = '<Email password>'
SEND_FROM   = '<Shared mailbox email>'
SUBJECT     = '<Subject>'
MAIL_BODY   = '<Email body>'
send_email(user,password,SEND_FROM,SEND_TO,SUBJECT,MAIL_BODY)
```